# Use a Spring JPA repository exclusively for tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

Using a repository in Spring is straightforward. For integration testing, I'd like to define a repository which provides test-specific methods without "polluting" the original repository.

**Example**

Let's say there is the following repo:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

For testing purposes I'd like to have something like the following but this repo shall only reside in a package in `src/test`.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserTestRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

When adding `@Autowired public UserTestRepo userTestRepo` in my test, then the following exception occurs:

`No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread`

Is it possible to have a distinct repo which is only accessible for testing?

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number of repository you want (That won;t be ideal). Also try annotating your Class from where you are autowiring your repository @Transactional.

Comment: Saved my day! Although its not clear for me why I have to make my integration test transactional to get a entity manager, which seems to be essential in a jpa/repository environment!? The cause of this problem in my case was a repository in test classes which extended a repository in classes. The parent repository worked fine while the child repository failed.